# iOS join multiple images

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uilabel, sprite

I want to build something like the screenshot below. I have a circle image and a line image. This is meant to denote a train route with multiple stops. Note that the list would be dynamic as the train can have any number of stops.

[![route][1]][1]

Whats the best way to go about building something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tableview to build this, and make a custom tableview cell with two UI parts, one for the image, and another for the stop name. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tableView` and black `UIView` in it. Show/hide this `UIView` as requirement. For stop name use `UILabel`.

Check below pattern,

1. for circle, (always be centrally align with label)
2. for upper strip,
3. lower strip.

More easier then image. now hide upper view for first stop and hide bottom view for last stop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like stepper control.You may use UISlider or UIProgressBar and make it customize to achieve this functionality.

There are many good examples on Github similar to your requirements. Please check some of them as below which may solve your problem.

- [AHStepperControl](https://github.com/ashh640/AHStepperControl)
- [PSProfileStepper](https://github.com/PKPranav/PSProfileStepper)
- [JKSteppedProgressBar](https://github.com/jkmathew/JKSteppedProgressBar)
- [CMSteppedProgressBar](https://github.com/Mycose/CMSteppedProgressBar)
- [ABSteppedProgressBar](https://github.com/antoninbiret/ABSteppedProgressBar)
- [ANProgressStepper](https://github.com/ayushn21/ANProgressStepper)

Comment: Interesting. Wonder if using a stepper would be easier than using a table view.